# Using Interface builder Xcode 4

Tags: interface-builder, xcode4.2

When using the interface builder, if I select a button that is in my layout, the interface builder immediately zooms into that button.

Is there any way I can stop that behaviour.

i.e. I want the interface builder to just select the button and not zoom in.

XCode 4.2 snow Leopard

Post-Script. I think the answer is "you can't". One other suggestion refers to making zoom shortcuts but that does seem to help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In response to my own question. As of 24 hours later I think the answer is
 "you can't".

One other suggestion found when researching in StackOverFlow refers to making zoom shortcuts but that does seem to help either.

Comment: If you mean it zooms in to 100% then yes, that is the way it works. You can't create IBActions or IBOutlets unless the stryboard view is at 100%. Gets a bit awkward with a large storyboard but there you go.